# Passing data through intent from class with extends runtimeException

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have implemented **VariosItensEncontradosException.java** with extend RuntimeException, when it called, i save items and later call activity for list this items. My problem is when i start activity a take one Exception.

The Class Exception

```
public class VariosItensEncontradosException extends RuntimeException {

  private final List<Item> itens;

  public VariosItensEncontradosException(List<Item> itens) {
    super("Vários lotes encontrados para o código informado");
    this.itens = itens;
  }

  public List<Item> getItens() {
    return itens;
  }
}
```

My Items

```
public final class Item implements Parcelable, Serializable {

  private String codigo;
  private String descricao;
  private transient BigDecimal fatorConversao;

  protected Item(Parcel in) {
    codigo = in.readString();
    descricao = in.readString();
    fatorConversao = new BigDecimal(in.readString());
  }

  public static final Creator<Item> CREATOR = new Creator<Item>() {
    @Override
    public Item createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
      return new Item(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Item[] newArray(int size) {
      return new Item[size];
    }
  };

  public String getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
  }

  public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
  }

  public BigDecimal getFatorConversao() {
    return fatorConversao;
  }

  public String descricao() {
    return String.format("%s - %s", getCodigo(), getDescricao());
  }

  @Override
  public int describeContents() {
    return hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(codigo);
    parcel.writeString(descricao);
    parcel.writeString(fatorConversao.toString());
  }

}
```

The way i call a new Activity

```
catch (VariosItensEncontradosException ex) {
      edtBarcode.setText("");
      SelecionarItemActivity.show(getActivity(), ex.getItens(), this);
```

And my Expception

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   android.modulo38.winthor.pcsist.com.br.modulo38, PID: 23067
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing
>   serializable object (name =
>   br.com.pcsist.winthor.modulo38.mobile.ui.expedicao.separacao.menu.item.ItemSeparacaoFragment)
>   at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1527) at
>   android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1475) at
>   android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724) at
>   android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408) at
>   android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157) at
>   android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764) at
>   android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8694) at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3082)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1520)
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4266) at
>   android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:54)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224) at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:708)
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4563) at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4531) at
>   br.com.pcsist.winthor.modulo38.mobile.ui.expedicao.selecionar_item.SelecionarItemActivity.show(SelecionarItemActivity.java:54)
>   at
>   br.com.pcsist.winthor.modulo38.mobile.ui.expedicao.separacao.menu.item.ItemSeparacaoFragment.separar(ItemSeparacaoFragment.java:201)
>   at
>   br.com.pcsist.winthor.modulo38.mobile.ui.expedicao.separacao.menu.item.ItemSeparacaoFragment.separar(ItemSeparacaoFragment.java:156)
>   at
>   br.com.pcsist.winthor.modulo38.mobile.ui.expedicao.separacao.menu.item.ItemSeparacaoFragment_ViewBinding$3.onEditorAction(ItemSeparacaoFragment_ViewBinding.java:65)
>   at android.widget.TextView.onEditorAction(TextView.java:4903) at
>   com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.performEditorAction(EditableInputConnection.java:138)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:372)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:93)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6130) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) Caused
>   by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1224)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1584)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1549)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1472)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>   at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1522) at
>   android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1475)  at
>   android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724)  at
>   android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408)  at
>   android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157)  at
>   android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764)  at
>   android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8694)  at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3082)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1520)
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4266)  at
>   android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:54)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:708)
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4563)  at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4531)  at
>   br.com.pcsist.winthor.modulo38.mobile.ui.expedicao.selecionar_item.SelecionarItemActivity.show(SelecionarItemActivity.java:54)
>   at
>   br.com.pcsist.winthor.modulo38.mobile.ui.expedicao.separacao.menu.item.ItemSeparacaoFragment.separar(ItemSeparacaoFragment.java:201)
>   at
>   br.com.pcsist.winthor.modulo38.mobile.ui.expedicao.separacao.menu.item.ItemSeparacaoFragment.separar(ItemSeparacaoFragment.java:156)
>   at
>   br.com.pcsist.winthor.modulo38.mobile.ui.expedicao.separacao.menu.item.ItemSeparacaoFragment_ViewBinding$3.onEditorAction(ItemSeparacaoFragment_ViewBinding.java:65)
>   at android.widget.TextView.onEditorAction(TextView.java:4903)  at
>   com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.performEditorAction(EditableInputConnection.java:138)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:372)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:93)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

Comment: The root cause is  `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText`. and the Problem is in `SelecionarItemActivity.java` line 54

Comment: Yeah ! But i dont know what i doing wrong. When i call this activity i pass the data items from "putSerielizableExtra()" or "putParceableExtra()' booth send this exception